# Need of raw socket in network

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, networking, protocols

What is the need of a raw socket. Apart from TCP and UDP when I want to use raw socket. The main difference is headers. In raw socket we
create our own header. What is the use of that. And why ping and traceroute use raw sockets. What is the problem arrives if it use TCP
or UDP.

Answer (score 2):

`ping` uses `icmp` which is specifically designed for network diagnosis, error reporting etc. which isn't for data transfer. That is one of the reason why `ping` uses `icmp`. It also doesn't require connection to be established between hosts. And doesn't require any server program to listen for any request.

Which packet `traceroute` uses is mostly  implementation specific. But Linux version of `traceroute` does use packet other than ICMP like UDP or TCP SYNC packets.